# How to get a JSON file (or something similar) with lightning data from http://en.blitzortung.org?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json

I am currently working on my school project - Android app that informs you about strong lightning strikes near your house in real time.

There are some websites like blitzortung.org or lightningmaps.org (or other), any ideas how can I get nice output file from one of these sites, so that I can obtain geographical data, determine whether it is near your house or not, and send a push notification for user? Displaying the strikes on the map are not needed.

I am using an Android Studio, Visual Studio 2015 as well as MS SQL database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get complete source code for this from following URL

https://github.com/wuan/bo-android

It's using data from lightningmaps.org

Comment: Thank you, I found nice things there :)

Comment: Great, kindly click on up arrow of this post so i may get some points ;-)

Comment: unfortunately I can't. only users with reputation above 15 can click on that. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Open Weather](https://openweathermap.org/api) or check this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29810/near-real-time-sources-of-lightning-strike-data).

For Push you can use FCM. Just google "How to implement GCM in android?" you will whole lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [blitzortung forum](http://en.blitzortung.org/forum.php):

> Please remember that Blitzortung data may not be used for commercial
>   purposes. General operator data access info: login to your main
>   Blitzortung Org account, and click the 'compendium' link under
>   'project area'. If you haven't already, you might also see
>   http://www.lightningmaps.org/doc/intro